# My hidden memory ghosts won't re spawn in the Paradox mission

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

I am trying to get the No Time To Explain exotic pulse rifle, so I looked up a video on how to do it and it tells me to find these three hidden ghosts that contain memories in the mission Paradox on Venus. Anyways, I followed the video to a tee and for some reason the last ghost didn't spawn, so I thought that if I restarted the mission it would fix itself, it didn't and now none of them are spawning, can somebody please tell me whats going on, if I need to finish the mission first, or if I should wait for the weekly reset for all of the ghosts to spawn?

**NOTE:** [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxGFyIW23x8) is the video I watched

Comment: What difficulty were you playing on? The ghosts are only available on Heroic difficulty, not Normal.

Comment: The Paradox Mission **must** be the daily heroic story for this to work.

Comment: @TravisJ this isn't correct. A few patches ago Bungie changed all of the timed exotic quests from TTK so that they can be started at any time. You do still need to play the mission on Heroic, though.

Comment: Do you have a link to that patch?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wipe at any point during the first phase of the mission.  I think if you die, the next ghosts do not spawn.  I assume the video mentions this but I can't watch currently.  If you do die, you will need to restart the entire mission, with the heroic difficulty, but I do not think you have to wait until the reset.